# what is a skeleton in rmi? How it is different from the stub file i kept on the client machine?

Tags: java, rmi, stub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a skeleton in a network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472176/what-is-a-skeleton-in-a-network)

what is a skeleton in rmi ? I created a stub file and kept one in the client machine and the same in the server machine. I didn't keep any *skeleton* file on the server machine and have been getting all right. What is actually a skeleton ? Is it the name given to a stub file on the server machine ? If that is true how can their opposite work be explained ?

Comment: @ skaffman No not a duplicate . I am asking is there any difference betwwen a stub and a skeleton files . Please read the whole question

Comment: Did you read the other question?  The title is different, the answer is the same.

Comment: @skaffman is quite right. Briefly, a skeleton is some code that sits on the server and translates the incoming RMI request into a call on your object. In modern RMI, this is handled transparently, so you never need to generate or manipulate skeletons yourself.

Comment: @ Tom Anderson so skeleton is just a stub file on the server.? The same stub file that is kept on the client machine ? And yes i removed the stub file from the server and then also could get the right result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115195/java-difference-between-stub-and-skeleton