# Java: Difference between stub and skeleton

Tags: java, web-services

What is the difference between stub and skeleton? As I know stub use java RMI and skeleton doesn't.

Comment: hi Gigal, Ramesh has given a proper answer . but if you could search in google you would find that in the first search result .. so please give a minimum try before asking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **[Stubs and Skeletons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/spec/rmi-arch2.html)**

> RMI uses a standard mechanism (employed in RPC systems) for communicating with remote objects: stubs and skeletons. A stub for a remote object acts as a client's local representative or proxy for the remote object. The caller invokes a method on the local stub which is responsible for carrying out the method call on the remote object. In RMI, a stub for a remote object implements the same set of remote interfaces that a remote object implements.

---

**When a stub's method is invoked, it does the following:**

- initiates a connection with the remote JVM containing the remote object,
- marshals (writes and transmits) the parameters to the remote JVM,
- waits for the result of the method invocation,
- unmarshals (reads) the return value or exception returned, and
- returns the value to the caller.

> The stub hides the serialization of parameters and the network-level communication in order to present a simple invocation mechanism to the caller.
>
> In the remote JVM, each remote object may have a corresponding skeleton (in Java 2 platform-only environments, skeletons are not required).

*The skeleton is responsible for dispatching the call to the actual remote object implementation.*

---

**When a skeleton receives an incoming method invocation it does the following:**

- unmarshals (reads) the parameters for the remote method,
- invokes the method on the actual remote object implementation, and
- marshals (writes and transmits) the result (return value or exception) to the caller.

> *In the Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.2 an additional stub protocol was introduced that eliminates the need for skeletons in Java 2 platform-only environments. Instead, generic code is used to carry out the duties performed by skeletons in JDK1.1. Stubs and skeletons are generated by the rmic compiler.*

---

[Reference:](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/spec/rmi-arch2.html)